# Adding watchlist. Watchlist not displaying added items Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to work on a project and one of the features is that users who are signed in should be able to visit a Watchlist page, which should display all of the listings that a user has added to their watchlist.

So far, I am redirected and receive the pop-up message when 'add to watchlist' is clicked but it does not bring up the button of 'remove from watchlist' and also when it redirects me to the watchlist page (where i should view the users entire watchlist), it shows me 'No watchlist found.'.

I have triple-checked and I am iterating properly (I think) but I don't know why it is not showing any of the watchlist)

URLS.PY

```
    path("add_watchlist/<int:listing_id>/", views.add_watchlist, name="add_watchlist"),
    path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
```

MODELS.PY

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Auction)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s watchlist"
```

LAYOUT.HTML

```
                    <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'all_category' %}?category={{ category.name}}">Category</a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'create_listing' %}">Sell</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'watchlist' %}">Watchlist</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
@login_required
def add_watchlist(request, listing_id):
    items = Auction.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    watched = Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user, item=listing_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if watched.exists():
            watched.delete()
            messages.success(request, 'Listing removed from watchlist')
            # messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Successfully deleted from your watchlist")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("watchlist"))
            
        else:
            watched, created = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
            watched.item.add(items)
            messages.success(request, 'Listing removed from watchlist')
            # messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Successfully added to your watchlist")
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("watchlist")) 

@login_required
def watchlist(request):
    watchlists = Watchlist.objects.all()
    context = {'watchlists':watchlists}
    return render(request, 'auctions/watchlist.html', context)
```

DETAILS.HTML

```
                            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                            <div class="my-2">
                                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add_watchlist' detail.id %}" class="form-inline">
                                    {% csrf_token%}
                                    
                                    {% if watched %}
                                        <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit" value="Remove from Watchlist" />
                                    {% else %}
                                        <input class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit" value="Add to Watchlist" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                        </div>
```

WATCHLIST.HTML

```
            <div class="container pb-4">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    {% for watchlist in watchlists %}
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
                            <a href={% url 'listing_detail' watchlist.id %} class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-1">
                                    {% if watchlist.image_url %}
                                        <img src='{{ watchlist.image_url }}' alt="{{ watchlist.title }}" style="width:100%">
                                    {% else %}
                                        <img src="https://demofree.sirv.com/nope-not-here.jpg">
                                    {% endif %}  
                                        <h5 class="card-title mb-0">{{ watchlist.title }}</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    {% empty %}
                        <p>No watchlist found.</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
```

#EDIT
I also tried to use a related name to the model to get the watchlist but it didnt work. Please see alteration below;

MODELS.PY

```
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Auction, related_name='watchlistings',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s watchlist"
```

WATCHLIST.HTML

```
                    {% for watchlist in items.watchlistings.all %}
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
                            <a href={% url 'listing_detail' watchlist.id %} class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm m-1">
                                    {% if watchlist.image_url %}
                                        <img src='{{ watchlist.image_url }}' alt="{{ watchlist.title }}" style="width:100%">
                                    {% else %}
                                        <img src="https://demofree.sirv.com/nope-not-here.jpg">
                                    {% endif %}  
                                        <h5 class="card-title mb-0">{{ watchlist.title }}</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    {% empty %}
                        <p>No watchlist found.</p>
                    {% endfor %}
```